# Call SQL Server Procedure with two parameters from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I have implemented some VBA code in Excel which calls a SQL Server stored procedure that expects two arguments: integer and date.

Problem: if I execute my VBA code in Excel, I get no data from my SQL Server procedure.

I don't get any error message, either.

If I execute my procedure in SQL Server Management Studio with

```
EXEC [dbo.spsClient] '123456' '01.01.2014'
```

I get some data from my SQL Server procedure. I think I have a problem to handle two arguments in VBA.

I implemented following code:

```
...
nr = 123456
datepoint = DateValue(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetData).Cells(4, 3))

Dim ADODBCmd As New ADODB.Command
With ADODBCmd
    .ActiveConnection = objconn
    .CommandTimeout = 500
    .CommandText = "dbo.spsClient"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter("@number", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, nr)
    .Parameters.Append ADODBCmd.CreateParameter("@date", adDate, adParamInput, datepoint)
    Set recordset = .Execute()
End With
```

Comment: Try sending a hard coded date as a string to eliminate format problems.  Examine the query with SQL Profiler running and see the what is actually being sent to the DB.

Comment: I also tried hard coded date and nr. It's still not working... :(

Comment: Capture from Profiler, copy-pasta the SQL into management studio and see whats up

Comment: @AlexK., I have tried in the SQL-Management studio and I get the results, which I'am excpecting.

Comment: @vc74: can you be more exact?

Comment: Is that the actual script? If so, you define a variable `date` and then pass `datePoint` as the second parameter.

Comment: @Gareth: it was just a missspelling. I'm sorry, about that. I corrected now in the post. It's still not working.

Comment: No worries, is that the actual code though? `Date` is a reserved word in VBA.

Comment: @Gareth: I'm worried, because I tried the last two hours to fix my easy problem. It was another missspelling problem. Sorry also about that. I correc my code.

Comment: Is it working now then?

Comment: @Gareth: Unfortunaly, not :( I will cry in the next time.

Comment: Can you modify the stored procedure to output the parameters to a table or similar?  Failing that use the profiler (as suggested above but I think you misunderstood) to capture exactly what is being passed in.  It's almost certainly the date not being right, but not being "wrong enough" to raise an error?  Also your first parameter isn't an integer, it's a varchar...?

Comment: Also, just noticed you used parameters.refresh but then go on to add two new parameters.  I am not sure, but won't this end up with four parameters, the original two with null values and two more with the same names and values set?  Maybe ditch the parameters.refresh and see if that helps...? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174223

Comment: What does the SP actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem: in the second Append.Parameters I forgot to validate the size, in this case ("50").

Thank's for helping me.